# STM32 Blue pill motor control

Tags: arduino, stm32, i2c, servo

I am working on a project in which a drone is being developed however I got into a problem where I cannot get the propellers to spin in specific situations. My question would be associated with usage of ESC's while I2C communication is also present. It is fairly clear for me how to use start the motors up and maintaining a constant speed, which is working properly in this case:

```c++
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //setupMPU(); //If this piece of line is commented out motors don't spin.

  myservo1.attach(PB1); 
  myservo2.attach(PB0);
  myservo3.attach(PA7); 
  myservo4.attach(PA6);

  for (int pos = 900; pos <= 1200; pos += 20) 
  {
    // in steps of 1 degree
    myservo3.writeMicroseconds(pos);
    myservo4.writeMicroseconds(pos);
    myservo1.writeMicroseconds(pos);
    myservo2.writeMicroseconds(pos);
    delay(200);
  }
```

In order to measure accelerations and angular velocities I use an MPU-6050 sensor and, as soon as function `setupMPU()` is commented out, propellers are not willing to spin at all. The mentioned method contains the following (it is just a simple configuration of an IMU sensor using I2C):

```c++
void setupMPU(){
  Wire.beginTransmission(0b1101000); //This is the I2C address of the MPU (b1101000/b1101001 for AC0 low/high datasheet sec. 9.2)
  Wire.write(0x6B); //Accessing the register 6B - Power Management (Sec. 4.28)
  Wire.write(0b00000000); //Setting SLEEP register to 0. (Required; see Note on p. 9)
  Wire.endTransmission();  
  Wire.beginTransmission(0b1101000); //I2C address of the MPU
  Wire.write(0x1B); //Accessing the register 1B - Gyroscope Configuration (Sec. 4.4) 
  Wire.write(0x00010000); //Setting the gyro to full scale +/- 250deg./s 
  Wire.endTransmission(); 
  Wire.beginTransmission(0b1101000); //I2C address of the MPU
  Wire.write(0x1C); //Accessing the register 1C - Acccelerometer Configuration (Sec. 4.5) 
  Wire.write(0b00010000); //Setting the accel to +/- 2g
  Wire.endTransmission(); 
}
```

Comment: What is in the `loop()` function?

Comment: I initially left loop() blank not to further complicate the issue.

Comment: Took me several hours to find out I did not call the Wire.begin() function at the beginning of setup(). Now motors spin up as expected.